# Binary Tree Search generate StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, exception, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I made a Binary Tree for searching a best prefix for a phone number but when i have a largest list of prefixes, the follow code sometimes generate a StackOverflowException on StartsWith() function.

BTreeNode.cs

```
public class BTreeNode<T>
{
    public BTreeNode(T item)
    {
        this.Item = item;
    }

    public T Item { get; set; }
    public BTreeNode<T> Left { get; set; }
    public BTreeNode<T> Right { get; set; }
}
```

BTree.cs

```
public class BTree
{
    public BTreeNode<string> Root { get; set; }

    public BTree(IEnumerable<string> enumerable)
    {
        if (enumerable == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(enumerable));
        }

        using (IEnumerator<string> enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                AddNode(enumerator.Current);
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddNode(string key)
    {
        if (Root == null)
        {
            Root = new BTreeNode<string>(key);
        }
        else
        {
            AddNode(key, Root);
        }
    }

    private void AddNode(string key, BTreeNode<string> current)
    {
        if (key.StartsWith(current.Item))
        {
            if (current.Left == null)
            {
                current.Left = new BTreeNode<string>(key);
            }
            else
            {
                AddNode(key, current.Left);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (current.Right == null)
            {
                current.Right = new BTreeNode<string>(key);
            }
            else
            {
                AddNode(key, current.Right);
            }
        }
    }

    public string Search(string key)
    {
        if (Root == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return Search(key, Root, null);
    }

    private string Search(string key, BTreeNode<string> current, BTreeNode<string> match)
    {
        if (current != null)
        {
            if (current.Left != null)
            {
                if (key.StartsWith(current.Left.Item))
                {
                    return Search(key, current.Left, current.Left);
                }
            }
            if (current.Right != null)
            {
                if (key.StartsWith(current.Item))
                {
                    return Search(key, current.Left, current);
                }

                if (key.Length >= current.Right.Item.Length)
                {
                    if (long.Parse(key) >= long.Parse(current.Right.Item))
                    {
                        return Search(key, current.Right, match);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (key.StartsWith(current.Item))
                {
                    return Search(key, current.Left, current);
                }
            }
        }

        return match?.Item;
    }
}
```

[Sample data](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/marcoantonira/ef3d12f8d3279a46c30494bc00d6cfd2/raw/564858ae3835d3f6654f3a93acefe2a1f0aa9bf3/sample.txt)

StackOverflowException occurred for example if i'm searching on loop the all sample data that i load to Binary Tree.

Any solution?

Comment: Please don't post code as external links, if the Gist gets deleted, this question becomes meaningless. Also, your first two links go to the same thing.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG i'm going to edit.

Comment: The only real problem I see in the code is that the code is recursive. This would not be a problem, for small amount of data. Unfortunately your sample has more than 35 000 data samples. And since the tree is not balanced, it is possible, that you call the same function too many times _(more than 35 000 times recursion)_. This can cause the problem

Answer (score 2):

I see no mechanism to balance this tree, so when you import a lot of data, some sub-branches can become very long. It is even possible that the whole tree is one linear branch, and doesn't split in multiple branches, especially when your list with sample data is ordered.

Some more advances trees, like a red-black tree, have a built-in mechanism to keep the tree balanced.

You have 35000 elements, which means a perfectly balanced tree should be not deeper than something around 15. (2^15 = 32768). But when the tree is completely unbalanced, you have one very long branch, which is almost the same as a single-linked list of 35000 elements, which are accessed recursively.

Comment: I've been studying the tree but I still can not figure out how I can implement the search I want. Can you give me just one more advice as I implement the search based on the largest "startswith" that exists in the tree from an input? Thanks for the advice.